# IFC : IfcReinforcingBar example

Tags: ifc, bim

I am using xBIM toolkit. I need to write bar (IfcReinforcingBar) and try to do this following wall creation example. But I am totally lost.
Does anybody already do this and could share is code with me ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: What have you tried already? Did you try following the example at https://docs.xbim.net/examples/proper-wall-in-3d.html ?

Comment: What issue are you having - you should pretty much be able to replace `IfcWallStandardCase` with `IfcReinforcingBar`. The Material Layer Set code will be irrelevant, and it's likely you want a different Geometric representation, but Swept solid should work.

Comment: Thank you Andy for your help. Yes I tried to transform wall into ReinforcingBar. It works not to bad just to add bar into model.
But you're right my main problem is for geometry. I am newbie in C# and I don't know how to play with IfcSweptDiskSolid and IfcIndexedPolyCurve. XBim documentation show me solution but don't explain how to reach it :-).

I suppose somebody already did it. That is why I ask for a link a source code to study it.